# ¿Por qué no se muestran todos las columnas de repuesta del procedimiento en el excel 2007?

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedure

Hace un momento me indicaron que realizara un reporte en excel sobre una tabla de ventas, lo que hice fue hace una conexión hacia la base de datos desde el excel y ejecutar un procedimiento que me devolviera las filas para se mostradas en la hoja de excel, pero al momento de realizar la ejecución desde el excel no me trae la data completa, lo que quiero decir es que no me trae la información de algunas columnas, pero cuando ejecuto el procedimiento en bd muestra la información completa.
No se si esta ignorando por el tipo de dato o me falta especificar algo en la configuración, pero no creo que sea la cantidad de información que retorna.
Estoy utilizando la versión 2007 de excel y antes lop intente con la versión 2010 y nada[image: Este es una captura de el resultado que me da y las columnas que salen vacías]

Ojala me puedan ayudar con este tema, si falta alguna tipo de información me la comentan.
gracias.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la información suministrada en este [enlace](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_archive/microsoft-query-from-excel-file-returns-empty/ef632a32-a79f-4515-a2d5-bfda74dc6c35)

> Cuando usted usa Microsoft Query, usted está atado a las reglas de la
>   base de datos, no a las reglas de Excel. Consecuentemente, usted debe
>   asegurarse que TODOS los valores en sus columnas fuente sean de tipo
>   TEXTO.

Mi recomendación es que "si necesita esta información usando Microsoft Query", modifique la consulta que esté usando para que todos los resultados sean NVARCHAR y que *(si son NULL o vacíos)*, los retorne con un valor por defecto.